# Unable to call function outside of original class due to lack of instance reference

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms on C#. I have two xaml pages linked to separate classes, MainPage and InputPage. What I'm trying to do is call NewPost with the text values of two named labels in InputPage, in order to create a new set of frames that is inserted into a stacklayout in MainPage. The issue I've encountered is that, with NewPost defined in the MainPage class, it requires an instance of MainPage (due to being non-static), which I can't find where this is/ should be instantiated publicly. Looking this up, I've gathered that either there's a simple solution that I've missed, or I'm going about this the complete wrong way.

The c# functions, in seperate classes `MainPage` and `InputPage` respectively

```cs
    public void NewPost(string title, string description)
    {  
        /*
           creating the frame set called task
        */ 
        MainPage.tasks.Children.Add(task);
    
    }
```

```cs
void entrySubmit(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MainPage.NewPost(titleBox.Text, descBox.Text);
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

The xaml elements concerned, in `MainPage` and `InputPage` .xaml

```xml
    <ScrollView
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Grid.RowSpan="5"
        Padding="4">
        <StackLayout x:Name="tasks">
    
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

```xml
    <Entry Placeholder="Title"
           x:Name="descBox">
    
        </Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Description"
               x:Name="titleBox">
        </Entry>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="Enter"
                Clicked="entrySubmit">
        </Button>
        <Button Text="Cancel"
                Clicked= "entryCancel">
        </Button>
```

Where MainPage appears to be created as the MainPage in App

```cs
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();

    }
```

Where InputPage is created, a button event handler in MainPage

```cs
void writeNew(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new InputPage());
    }
```

I have tried:

- Moving the NewPost function into MainPage or another class - this results in the xaml element it needs to access being out of scope

  - Using `x:FieldModifier` to change the x:Name to public - this seemed to have no effect
- Changing NewPost to static, as well as the function that calls NewPost - Resulting in the need for object reference being moved to the xaml element IDs

  The end result of this mostly comes down to not providing an object reference of MainPage for functions or values. At least pointers on how this should be done would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're correct that things should not be static. If one component needs to interact with another component, there are lots of options. You could use events, for example. Can you show the code where your pages get created and shown?

Comment: Do you want to pass some non-static value in the page?